# How to include the server name in the filename of an apache log?

Tags: linux, apache, filenames, logging

I want to configure apache so that the access and error logs generated from apache include are named as follows:

```
<server-name>_access_<timestamp>
<server-name>_error_<timestamp>
```

I have the timestamp part figured out using rotatelogs:

```
CustomLog logs/access_log combined
CustomLog "|bin/rotatelogs -l /var/logs/access_%Y-%m-%d 86400" common
```

The part that I cannot figulre out is how to include the server name in the filename.  I am configuring Apache on a linux box.

Regards,
Mohan

Answer (score 2):

It appears that as recent as Apache HTTPD 2.4, no feature provides this capability.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_log_config.html#customlog

If you wanted to something tricky, you could use a pipe similar to how you're accomplishing your timestamp problem and have a script try to determine the VirtualHost. Not sure how you'd accomplish that.

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution, in the http.conf use:

```
CustomLog "|$/usr/local/apache2/conf/my_log.pl" common
```

create a file in /usr/local/apache2/conf/my_log.pl with:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $path="/usr/local/apache2/logs";
my $access="_access.log";
my $hostname=`hostname`;
chomp($hostname);
my $filename="${path}/${hostname}${access}";

$|=1; # Use unbuffered output

open (STDOUT, ">> $filename") or die $!;

while(<STDIN>) {
    print STDOUT $_;
}
```

add the execution perm.:

```
chmod a+x /usr/local/apache2/conf/my_log.pl
```

Answer (score -1):

Check out [the mod_log_config documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_log_config.html); iIt looks like you want either `%v` or `%V`:

```
%...v    The canonical ServerName of the server serving the request.
%...V    The server name according to the UseCanonicalName setting.
```

Comment: These settings refer to the formatting of the individual log messages, not the name of the log file itself.